# Custom Endless ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

I'm trying to do something like endless adapter but not able to accomplish it and as a result my app is crashing.
What i tried to do is that initially i wanted loaded 10items in listview and add foorterview at the end of listview.If user clicks on the footerview than 10 more item is loaded in the listview.

But when i start that activity only footerview appears and after few seconds application crashes.
I have posted the relevant code below:

```
int questionsPerPage = 10;
boolean loadingMore = false;
ArrayList<DataHolder> myquestionsResults;
QuestionListViewAdapter adapter;

//in onCreate
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_questions);
    // add the footer before adding the adapter, else the footer will not
    // load!
    View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
            R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
            thread.start();
        }
    });
    lv.addFooterView(footerView);
    myquestionsResults = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
    adapter = new QuestionListViewAdapter(this, myquestionsResults);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            DataHolder fullObject = (DataHolder) o;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    ViewMyQuestion.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", fullObject.getId());
            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });

    // Load the first 10 items
    Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
    thread.start();
}// End of onCreate

private ArrayList<DataHolder> GetMyQuestionsResult() {
    ArrayList<DataHolder> myquestionInfo = new ArrayList<DataHolder>();
    HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
    db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
    db.getReadableDatabase();
    hm = db.getUserDetails();
    db.close();
    String un = hm.get("username");

    uf = new UserFunctions();
    JSONArray json = uf.getQuestionsByUsername(un);
    int x = json.length();
    try {
        if (x > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                ja = json.getJSONArray(i);
                id = ja.getString(0);
                userName = ja.getString(1);
                question = ja.getString(2);
                tag1 = ja.getString(3);
                tag2 = ja.getString(4);
                tag3 = ja.getString(5);
                posted_on = ja.getString(6);
                DataHolder qih = new DataHolder();
                qih.setId(id);
                qih.setUserName(userName);
                qih.setQuestion(question);
                qih.setTag1(tag1);
                qih.setTag2(tag2);
                qih.setTag3(tag3);
                qih.setQuestionPostedOn(posted_on);
                myquestionInfo.add(qih);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return myquestionInfo;
}
// Runnable to load the items
private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Set flag so we cant load new items 2 at the same time
        loadingMore = true;

        // Reset the array that holds the new items


        // Get 10 new listitems
        for (int i = 0; i < questionsPerPage; i++) {
            // Fill the item with some bogus information
            myquestionsResults.add(GetMyQuestionsResult().get(i));

        }

        // Done! now continue on the UI thread
        runOnUiThread(returnRes);

    }
};

// Since we cant update our UI from a thread this Runnable takes care of
// that!
private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void run() {

        // Tell to the adapter that changes have been made, this will cause
        // the list to refresh
        ((BaseAdapter) lv.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Done loading more.
        loadingMore = false;
    }
};
```

Below is my logcat messages:

```
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.ClassCastException:    android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.vervecoders.cuqu.MyQuestions$3.run(MyQuestions.java:275)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 06:00:03.799: E/AndroidRuntime(280):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

After updating code it crashed again.Following are the new logcat messages:

```
08-27 07:38:47.751: I/dalvikvm(349): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-27 07:38:47.751: I/dalvikvm(349):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x4001d8e0 self=0xccb0
08-27 07:38:47.751: I/dalvikvm(349):   | sysTid=349 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345026008
08-27 07:38:47.751: I/dalvikvm(349):   | schedstat=( 33038897911 15262681460 1352 )
08-27 07:38:47.751: I/dalvikvm(349):   at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:~123)
08-27 07:38:47.765: I/dalvikvm(349):   at com.vervecoders.cuqu.MyQuestions$3.run(MyQuestions.java:267)
08-27 07:38:47.765: I/dalvikvm(349):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-27 07:38:47.771: I/dalvikvm(349):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 07:38:47.771: I/dalvikvm(349):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 07:38:47.771: I/dalvikvm(349):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 07:38:47.785: I/dalvikvm(349):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 07:38:47.785: I/dalvikvm(349):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 07:38:47.785: I/dalvikvm(349):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 07:38:47.785: I/dalvikvm(349):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 07:38:47.785: I/dalvikvm(349):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 07:38:47.811: D/AndroidRuntime(349): Shutting down VM
08-27 07:38:47.811: W/dalvikvm(349): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:123)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.vervecoders.cuqu.MyQuestions$3.run(MyQuestions.java:267)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-27 07:38:47.845: E/AndroidRuntime(349):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
((ArrayList<DataHolder>) lv.getAdapter()).add(myquestionsResults.get(i));
```

Why are you casting the adapter to an ArrayList? This probably causes the ClassCastException

Try adding the new items to your myquestionsResults, and then notifying the adapter.

Better yet, you can add a method add() (or even addAll()) to your implementation of QuestionListViewAdapter, that will add the items to the list and invoke notifyDataSetChanged(). In that case you could make your adapter a member variable and use it directly, and not getting it from the cached ListView.

Comment: thanks for your response.I tried to add new items to myquestionsResults but it didnt solve the problem.Program ran for few seconds and it crashed afterwards.
I removed the part where i was casting and did something like myquestionsResults.add(myQuestionsResults.get(i))I have posted new logcat meesages in questions pls do take note about it.thank you

Comment: Also myquestionsResults.add(myQuestionsResults.get(i)) seems to be  adding the stuff from the myquestionsResults to itself - it might result in memory overflow, because you're it's never going to stop adding.

Comment: Bartosz Filipowicz thanks for the response.I have update code.Yes its causing memomry overflow.I also tried to do 'myquestionsResults.add(GetMyQuestionsResults().get(i))' but same thing memory overflow and crash at the end.

Comment: Hey, I think the problem is still in the loop. This part: for (int i = 0; i < myquestionsResults.size(); i++) is not correct in my opinion. It should not be there at all. First of all in the loadMoreItems runnable you are doing this: myquestionsResults = new ArrayList<DataHolder>() which is reseting the datasource. Remove this line :) Add the items to an existing ArrayList in loadMoreResults, and the only thing you should do in the returnRes runnable is to invoke notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: thanks for the response.I removed that part of the loop also in resturnRes i just kept the line of code which invokes notfiyDataSetChanged().Now it worked but the problem is that when i scroll down it loads the same items again so basically its like 1-10items>scroll down>1-10items instead of 1-10items>scroll down>11-20items.Im updating the changes made in code in the above code.thank you

Comment: I would guess it's this line:  for (int i = 0; i < questionsPerPage; i++) {
myquestionsResults.add(GetMyQuestionsResult().get(i));

        }
It always gets the results from 0 to questionsPerPage, while what you really need is to get questions from last item that is being displayed to the last item being displayed + 10. This could look like that: 
int lastItemDisplayedIndex = myquestionsResults.size();
for (int i = lastItemDisplayedIndex; i < lastItemDisplayedIndex + 10; i++) {
myquestionsResults.add(GetMyQuestionsResult().get(i));

        }